# Using ezStore123 CMS System and want to change layout?

Tags: asp.net

hello all im using a known cms system or maybe old cms system. its a simple ASP.NET application that was hand coded my problem is minor. This cms displays a catalog type website with products from a database. the display looks like its using an html file to house the catalog what i want to do is change that html file to another layout. ive been trying to find the systemdefs and libarary but no luck does anyone have an idea where these settings may be stored?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the page elements.  More specifically, look at the Stylesheet references.  If you can locate the stylesheets, it would be a step in the right direction.

An easy way to look at HTML code, is by installing FireBug (a firefox plugin).  You can analyze elements on your page by simply clicking on them.

Aside from that, the issue is not entirely clear.  Are you sure that HTML file exists, and is not generated by ASP.NET?

Comment: when i look at the asp file for the catalog it just has a for loop to display all the tables for the products i saw the css files but no help also the constants they used for the layout. so im guessing that theres an external html file used